# Use repeat loop to collect all capsules | Coding platform question

Tags: loops

So I'm teaching younger students coding on this coding platform, and there's this challenge under repeat loops which I cannot seem to find the answer to.

So here's the thing. We've got two characters, the monkey and the beaver. The beaver acts as a bridge to prevent the monkey from falling in the water. Characters can use the following methods to move: `forward(number of steps)` and `turn(left, right or back)`.

I've come up with this:

```
monkey.forward(4)

repeat(2) {
  monkey.turn(back)
  monkey.forward(2)
  beaver.forward(2)
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be the right solution as I'm only getting two stars. I know this might be subjective in a way, but is there a "more practical" way to solve this challenge?

[image]